# Using Html/CSS, how to display overlapped/composed UNICODE characters (without using diacriticals marks)?

Tags: html, css, unicode, combinations

Currently, I search to display 2 characters equivalent to `|<` and `>|` where

`<` = 0x2BC7 ⯇
 
`>` = 0x2BC8 ⯈
`|` = 0x6C (letter 'l')

On first message, I requested that vertical is represented by `|` = 0x2503 unicode character, but this character, in Arial, is not defined correctly on Chrome and on Edge Chromium.

When HTML code and style are following

```
div.std > span.char
    {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:80px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    }

<div class='std'>
    <span class='char'><span class='bar'>&nbsp;l</span><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char'><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='bar'>l&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
```

On Chrome browser, I get following output

[image]

The 2 left characters must be composed so that `|` character is linked to left point of triangle.

The 2 right characters must be composed so that `|` character is linked to right point of triangle.

**How can I do ?**

This display is use to define 4 buttons to allow navigation in a list.

For this reason, it is important that

1. all buttons have same height
2. button |< and >| have same width
3. button < and > have same width
4. all characters are centered in green rectangle
5. alls gaps between 2 successive buttons have same width

**It is also important that solution proposed works on any browser.**

PS: centered means that left and right paddings are equal for all characters and top and bottom paddings are also equal for all characters.

For example in this question, 2 things are not correct.

1. in first and last bloc, bar and triangle characters are not linked together
2. left padding of first bloc is too large (not= right padding)
3. right padding of last bloc is too large (not= left padding)

Comment: why not simply using an icon or build this using CSS or SVG? why trying to combine two unicode?

Comment: for the fun ! for the challenge ! to learn complexity of HTML. I know how to do using SVG, but I search a pure solution using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: no need unicode if you want a CSS solution, you can build it using different techniques, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/23cuynzk/

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. Why don't you post another answer with some explanation on this solution ? That's first time that I see it is possible to create another character using only CSS. Don't forget to indicate the inconvenience if there exists. (font color or background color or background size)

Comment: updated my answer. I actually don't see any inconvenience because you have full control over everything (width, height, color, padding, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Use a font that will always render the same and rely on `letter-spacing` to remove the unwanted space:

```css
.uni {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

.uni span:first-child,
.uni span:last-child {
  letter-spacing: -0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="uni">
  <span>&#x2503;&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;&#x2503;</span>
</div>

<div class="uni" style="font-size:30px;">
  <span>&#x2503;&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;&#x2503;</span>
</div>

<div class="uni" style="font-size:50px;">
  <span>&#x2503;&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC7;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;</span>
  <span>&#x2BC8;&#x2503;</span>
</div>
```

Or simply use CSS to build the shape and you can easily control everything:

```css
.arrow-1 {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   margin:0 5px;
   display:inline-block;
   border:15px solid yellow; /* control the padding*/
   padding-left:5px; /* control the width of the bar */
   background:
     linear-gradient(#000,#000) left,
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,#000 50%) top    content-box,
     linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49.5%,#000 50%) bottom content-box,
     yellow;
   background-size:
    5px 100%, /* same as padding-left */
    100% 50%,
    100% 50%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.arrow-2 {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   margin:0 5px;
   display:inline-block;
   border:15px solid yellow; /* control the padding*/
   background:
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,#000 50%) top   ,
     linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49.5%,#000 50%) bottom,
     yellow;
   background-size:100% 50%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-1">
</div>

<div class="arrow-2">
</div>

<div class="arrow-2" style="transform:scaleX(-1)">
</div>

<div class="arrow-1" style="transform:scaleX(-1)">
</div>
```

Comment: Using letter-spacing CCS is a good tricks when using monospace characters but for any font this is not the better solution. But I vote UP for the idea concept.

Comment: I regret that you have use a strange monospace font. Please, can you change your answer using Consolas so that your solution is more general !

Comment: @schlebe the main idea is not using the letter-spacing but to use the same font for your unicode to make sure it render the same everywhere so that you don't have to think for each browser/OS

Comment: I understand. I have a solution for any font (Consolas or Arial) that works correctly on any browser but I found that your idea to work with letter-spacing is interesting. I will come back later, because I want to explain all my work for new solution. Your solution doesn't work on any browser when Arial font is used. The font must absolutely be monospace.

Comment: 1 little remark (I will delete it after 1 or 2 days). I like your first solution but there are some problem when character have a colored background. Remark: if you change your example I rate you to stop using character 0x2503 by using another character (perhaps | in monospace or l (l as landscape) if you use sans serif font.

Answer (score 0):

In using only CSS, I have obtained following result

[image]

This can be done using following code

```css
span.bar-triangle
 {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 1.82ch;
 }
span.bar-triangle > span.bar
 {
 position:relative;
 padding-left:10px;
 background-color: transparent;
 }
span.bar-triangle > span.triangle
 {
 background-color: transparent;
 position:relative;
 left: -0.40ch;
 }
span.triangle-bar
 {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 1.82ch;
 }
span.triangle-bar > span.triangle
 {
 padding-right:0.24ch;
 background-color: transparent;
 }
span.triangle-bar > span.bar
 {
 position:relative;
 left: -0.60ch;
 background-color: transparent;
 }
div
 {
 font-family: Arial;
 line-height:452%;
 font-size:20
 }
div > span.char
 {
 background-color: yellow;
 font-size: 80px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <span class='char bar-triangle'><span class='bar'>l</span><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC7;</span></span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC7;</span>
    <span class='char'>&#x2BC8;</span>
    <span class='char triangle-bar'><span class='triangle'>&#x2BC8;</span><span class='bar'>l</span></span>
</div>
```

```
span.bar-triangle
    {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 1.82ch;
    }
```

This code fix width of `bar-triangle` rectangle.
Changing `display` to `inline-block` is necessary to fix the width.

```
span.bar-triangle > span.bar
    {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

This code move `bar` character to the right so that left space is more large.
Parameter `background-color` is set to transparent because background's color is set in `bar-triangle` rectangle.

```
span.bar-triangle > span.triangle
    {
    background-color: transparent;
    position:relative;
    left: -0.40ch;
    }
```

This code shifts triangle's character to the left until left angle touch vertical bar.

```
span.triangle-bar
    {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 1.82ch;
    }
```

As for `bar-triangle`, this code fixes width of `triangle-bar` rectangle.

```
span.triangle-bar > span.triangle
    {
    padding-right:0.24ch;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

This code increment right padding to that left-paddind and right padding are equal and composed character continue to be centered in `triangle-bar` rectangle.

```
span.triangle-bar > span.bar
    {
    position:relative;
    left: -0.60ch;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

This code shifts vertical bar to the left so that right's angle touches vertical bar.

```
div
    {
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height:452%;
    font-size:20
    }
```

This code set font's family.
The `line-height` parameter is used to grow composed character rectangle height. 
The `font-size` parameter is used to fix gap between yellow rectangle.

```
div > span.char
    {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 80px;
    }
```

This code set backgroung's color of button's rectangle and size of character displayed in rectangles.

If `line-height` parameter is not used, we obtain following result

[image]

There exists perhaps another solution to avoid to use `line-height` but I don't find it.

Another possibility, is to replace `<span class='char'>` by `<div>`.

Comment: The biggest inconvenience is that the characters render differently based on the browser and the OS so even if you manually set left/top it will work for only a particular case. Your code is not working for me for example.